# Rails + GraphQl + Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, graphql

good night to every one. I need help to get out from where I'm stuck ... soo, I just start work with GraphQl / Rails and Rspec .. and I've trying to write my first test (rspec-rails) for GraphQl ("graphql", "~> 1.9") mutations, but I really can't understand what's missing in the code ...

**discount_type.rb**

```
module Types
  class DiscountType < Types::BaseObject
    field :client_id, Int, null: true
    field :name, String, null: true
    field :description, String, null: true
    field :img, String, null: true
    field :actual_price, Float, null: true
    field :original_price, Float, null: true
  end
end
```

**client_type.rb**

```
module Types
  class ClientType < Types::BaseObject   
    field :name, String, null: false
    field :information, String, null: false  
  end
end
```

**client_factory.rb**

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :client do
    sequence(:name) { "Client Name" }
    sequence(:information) { "first client improved" }
  end
end
```

**discount_factory.rb**

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :discount do
    client
    sequence(:img) { "..." }
    sequence(:name) { "first product" }
    sequence(:description) { "my description" }
    sequence(:client_id) { "1" }
    sequence(:original_price) { "10" }
    sequence(:actual_price) { "0.8" }
  end
end
```

**create_client.rb** [mutation]

```
module Mutations
  class CreateClient < BaseMutation
    argument :name, String, required: true
    argument :information, String, required: true
    field :client, Types::ClientType, null: true
    field :errors, [String], null: true
    def resolve(name:, information:)
      client = Client.new(name: name, information: information)
      if discount.save
        { client: client, errors: [] }
      else
        { client: nil, errors: client.errors.full_messages}
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**create_discount.rb** [mutation]

```
module Mutations
  class CreateDiscount < BaseMutation
    argument :client_id, ID, required: true
    argument :name, String, required: true
    argument :description, String, required: true
    argument :img, String, required: true
    argument :original_price, Float, required: true
    argument :actual_price, Float, required: true
    field :discount, Types::DiscountType, null: true
    field :errors, [String], null: true
    def resolve(client_id:, name:, description:, img:, actual_price:, original_price:)
      discount = Discount.new(
          client_id: client_id, name: name, actual_price: actual_price,
          original_price: original_price, img: img, description: description,
      )
      if discount.save
        { discount: discount, errors: [] }
      else
        { discount: nil, errors: discount.errors.full_messages }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**create_discount_spec.rb**

```
require 'rails_helper'
module Mutations
  RSpec.describe Discount, type: :request do
    describe '.resolve' do
      it 'creates a discount' do
        expect do
          client = create(:client)
          post '/graphql', params: {
              query: <<~GQL
                      mutation { createDiscount(
                        input: {
                            clientId: '#{client.id}'
                            name: 'mais um produto'
                            description: '...'
                            originalPrice: '1'
                            actualPrice: '0.8'
                            img: '....'
                        }
                    ) { clientId img name description originalPrice actualPrice }
                    }
                }
              GQL
          }
        end.to change { Discount.count }.by(1)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**spec output**

```
Run options: include {:full_description=>/Discount/}

expected `Discount.count` to have changed by 1, but was changed by 0

  0) Discount.resolve creates a discount
     Failure/Error:
       expect do
         client = create(:client)
         post '/graphql', params: {
             query: <<~GQL
                     mutation { createDiscount(
                       input: {
                           clientId: '#{client.id}'
                           name: 'mais um produto'
                           description: '...'
                           originalPrice: '1'

       expected `Discount.count` to have changed by 1, but was changed by 0
     # ./spec/graphql/mutations/discounts/create_discount_spec.rb:8:in `block (3 levels) in <module:Mutations>'

1 example, 1 failure, 0 passed

Finished in 1.198049 seconds
```

I did this **public Gist** and call for help .. Help !
https://gist.github.com/eduardovrocha/09cf224fd08341c9d9f10c4169d5011a

It's public .. soo anyone can improve. I accept links, tutorial .. youtube videos .. any kind of help it's welcome

Comment: hard to say what's wrong but here is a couple of things I'd try: 1. try adding `binding.pry` inside `resolve` and follow through the steps. 2. remove the `if` branch and just do `discount.save!` to see if any validation errors are being raised.

Comment: hy man @dimanyc tnks for answer ! The problem that's is freak me out is outside the test's every thing work's fine .. that's why I'm confused and can't find some great documentation online .. I try to follow some tutorials, but nothing help's

Comment: Yes, I've been there. Testing GraphQL can be really painful. Have you tried any of the two steps I mentioned?

Comment: I always find it helpful to check if errors are equal to an empty array before checking for the actual .count change. In this way rspec will fail with `expected [] but got "error message" instead` and you can debug it easier.

Comment: Have you try to output the response of the query ? GraphQL is probably returning to you what's wrong with your request. It might help you to remove your `post 'graphql` from the `expect` and `puts response` (within the `expect`). You can also add test regarding the output before ensuring that the db was updated.

Answer (score 4):

Breaking this down will help you debug.

Create a `GraphQL::Resolver` abstraction which gets called in a Mutation classes's `resolve` method. This will be a Plain Old Ruby Object! You can test it like any other class. Then you know the resolver logic is sound and you can rule that part of the system out.

```
module Mutations
  class CreateDiscount < BaseMutation
    argument :client_id, ID, required: true
    argument :name, String, required: true
    argument :description, String, required: true
    argument :img, String, required: true
    argument :original_price, Float, required: true
    argument :actual_price, Float, required: true
    field :discount, Types::DiscountType, null: true
    field :errors, [String], null: true
    def resolve(args**)
      ::Mutations::Resolvers::CreateDiscount.resolve(args**)
    end
  end
end

module Mutations
  module Resolvers
    class CreateDiscount
    def self.resolve(args**)
      discount = Discount.new(
          client_id: client_id, name: name, actual_price: actual_price,
          original_price: original_price, img: img, description: description,
      )
      if discount.save
        { discount: discount, errors: [] }
      else
        { discount: nil, errors: discount.errors.full_messages }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Okay. So then you've rule out the **resolving logic**. Still an issue?

Try sending this mutation your self in GraphiQL. 1. this is good practice for using GraphQL and 2. you'll be able to inspect the Rails logs as you go. May give you a clue.

Still an issue?

I don't think your http request is formed correctly, try something like the following.

```
# This is what mine look like at least
let(:query) do
  <<~GRAPHQL
    mutation anyName($input: CreateATing!) {
      createATing(input: $input) {
        fields
      }
    }
  GRAPHQL
end
let(:variables) do
  {
    input: {
      input_foo: 'bar'
    }
  }
end

before do
  post '/graphql', query: query, variables: variables
end
```